# Does New-Object have a memory leak?

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, powershell-3.0

Using Powershell v3, I'm using the .net library class `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` and `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` to query a list of properties from users in a domain. The code for this is basically [found here](https://blog.schmijos.ch/2013/09/27/ad-export-with-get-qaduser-is-too-slow/).

The only thing you need to add, is a line `$ds.PageSize=1000` in between lines `$ds.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'` and `$ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($properties)`. This will remove the limit of only grabbing 1000 users.

The number of users from one domain (we'll call it `domain1`) I have has over 80,000. Another domain (we'll call this `domain2`) has over 200,000 users.

If I run the code on `domain1`, it takes roughly 12 minutes (which is fantastic compared to the 24 hours `Get-QADUser` was taking). However, after the script is finished in the PowerShell window, I notice a memory hog is left of about 500mb. `Domain2` leaves a memory hog of about `1.5gb`.

**Note:** the memory leak with `Get-QADUser` is much much **MUCH worse**. `Domain2` leaves a memory hog of about 6gb and takes roughly 72 hours to complete (vs less than an hour with the .net class).

The only way to free the memory is to close the PowerShell window. But what if I want to write a script to invoke all these domains scripts to run them one after the other? I would run out of memory after getting to the 6th script.

The only thing I can think of is `New-Object` is creating a constructor and does not have a destructor (unlike java). I've tried using the `[System.GC]::Collect()` during the loop iterations, but this has had no affect.

Is there a reason? Is it solvable or am I stuck with this?

Comment: I don't have an answer off-hand, but I can tell you what you're seeing is not specific to `New-Object`.  Even doing a simple test of using `Get-Content` to store a large amount of data in a variable while run from a .ps1 file seems to cache the data in memory, even though that variable isn't available directly(unless declaring scope or dot sourcing) when it's done running. I don't think what you're seeing is a true memory leak. It's "normal."

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note: If there actually is a memory leak, you can just run the script in a new shell:

```
powershell { <# your code here #> }
```

As for the leak, as long as you have any variables that reference an object that holds on to large data it cannot be collected. You may have luck by using a memory profiler to look at what is still in memory and why. As far as I can see, if you use that code in a script file and execute the script (with `&`, not with `.`!), then this shouldn't really happen, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a memory profiler due to company has restricted us from using any tools, programs, compilers, or anything (including something like rsat tools from Microsoft) that does not already come with the pc set by IT. Luckily, IT installed .net so I can use those libraries. The only thing I'm allowed to use is Power GUI and Powershell v3 (I can't even upgrade to v5). I will try the suggestion on executing the code under a new powershell process though, and see how that goes. Thanks.

Comment: This definately works and the memory is cleared out. I just need to figure out how to pass through arguments to it.

Comment: @FiddleFreak: Just pass them normally. If you're calling a script, then just append the arguments, e.g. `powershell -File foo.ps1 arg1 arg2 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's `$table` that is using all the memory. Why don't you write the collected data directly to a file, instead of adding it to the array?