# PowerShell Decompress GZip Pipe using lots of memory

Tags: powershell, gzip, gzipstream

I'm writing a powershell Cmdlet to accept a list of files references to gzipped files and to decompress them and put their text lines on the pipeline.  I have something functioning, but it's using tons of memory.  What's interesting is that after is completed, if I run [System.GC]::Collect() at the powershell prompt, it will free up the memory.  I tried running it inside the loop, but it affected performance.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.  I thought one of the benefits of using pipelines is to conserve memory.  Even if I pass it a single file reference it uses more memory then the size of the file.

Here's my code.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Accepts GZip files piped in and outputs decrompessed text to the pipe.

.DESCRIPTION
You can use this function to pipe a list of serveral gzipped files.  They will then be decompress and concatenated
and the text will be written to the output where it can be piped to another function.

.PARAMETER PipedFile
A list of gzipped file references.

.EXAMPLE
Get-ChildItem "*.gz" | Decompress-Gzip

#>
Function Decompress-GZip {
    Param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [System.IO.FileInfo]$PipedFile

    )

    Process {

        If ( $PipedFile.Exists -eq $False) {
          Write-Host "File $PipedFile does not exist. Skipping."
          return
        }

        $BUFFER_SIZE = 65536

        $infile = $PipedFile.FullName


        $inputfile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
        $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $inputfile, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        try {
            $buffer = New-Object byte[]($BUFFER_SIZE)

            While (($read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, $BUFFER_SIZE)) -gt 0) {
                $str = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($buffer,0,$read)
                $temp = $str -split "`r`n"
                if ($temp.Length -gt 0) {
                    if ($lastLine) {
                        $temp[0] = $lastLine + $temp[0]
                    }
                    if ($temp.Length -gt 1) {
                        Write-Output $temp[0..($temp.Length-2)]
                    }
                    $lastLine = $temp[($temp.Length-1)]
                }
            }
        } finally {
         $gzipStream.Close()
         $inputfile.Close()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968966/does-new-object-have-a-memory-leak but not quite since your "GC collect" works. If you're working with dozens or hundreds of files, perhaps running the "GC collect" only once every three/ten or so files can improve performance and keep memory usage down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the OP seems to be: "What am I doing wrong?".

I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong. As the OP states, the memory returns to normal after a GC occurs. And unless there's a perf problem, either within the script, or within the rest of the system, I so no reason to say there's a problem.

The OP is not specific enough to know: 1. If memory use is related to the size of the buffer? 2. Or if it is related to size of file? If size of file is around 65K then it will be pretty difficult to determine.

Assuming memory use is related to size of the buffer, it becomes clear why the memory is several times the size of the buffer when one looks at the copies. 1. There is a copy made due to `GetString`. 2. Another made due to `-split`. 3. Another due to `Write-Output` of `$temp`. 4. Depending on implementation of `System.IO.Compression.GzipStream` and `System.IO.FileStream` they could each have their own buffer of unknown sizes. So that's at least 4X 65K.

Comment: So, the reason why I posted this is because my script is using a 64k buffer for steaming but when I unzip a single 350 mb gzipped file, the memory climbs and climbs past 7gb. It does level off there though so I guess it's ok.  I just can't imagine what's getting created and recreated from this code to cause the memory usage to increase so much.

Comment: Knowing that is helpful, but you should put that detail in the OP, rather than in a comment so anyone else reading your question will readily find it. If you want to dig into this behavior in more depth you can use Windbg along with SOS extension to examine the set of objects on the heap. There are a number of sources of info on using SOS (on SO and on the web), but the easiest way I've found is to run PS under Windbg. Break into the debugger when you want (Ctrl-Break) and then execute `.cordll -l` and then `!sos.help` to get help. I think !gchandles is the right command for this.